# get latest value on server on every phone app install

Tags: android, android-asynctask, home-automation

In  my home automatin app  as i comunicate with ardunio . as i click on light button its on ,as a reslut light on but as someone else in home when open app , there light off , how to get every user app instlled in home latest values.
 i am using async task
what should i do for this ?
how to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use FCM (google Firebase) for notifying other apps for last value.Each time value changes by any of apps a push notification will be sent in order to notify others.you can receive and handle this push in your app.Google for some sample it's easy to find.

Comment: as i my app communicate with my server router+zigbee  as i run app working but if some else use it not update either light on or off ,please bro little more detail i am not get it

Comment: i am using async task to do this

Comment: see this
https://developers.intercom.com/v2.0/docs/android-fcm-push-notifications
and you have to work on both sides.Your app and your server.